# Setting up Sonarqube to work with Scala+Akka properly

Tags: scala, sonarqube, code-coverage

I made a small service using Scala + Akka. The service works fine but the problem is that I need to put it into CI that uses Sonarqube. This brings the problem that I do not know how to solve:
**The Code coverage - goes beyond bad**.

When using IntelliJ to count CC the values oscillate around 70-80%.
We are using Maven as a management tool and JaCoCo plugin for Code Coverage. The CC values go down to 33% with the minimal degree of CC being 40%.

We are using **Scala version 2.13.5, Akka 2.6.13, Jacoco plugin 0.8.6**.

I've made experiments with Scoverage but it didn't work well and I've had multiple compatibility problems. Is there a setup that may help boot up the code coverage?